# Is Acetyl-CoA ever transported out of the cell, and in that case how?

Tags: metabolism, fat-metabolism

Acetyl-CoA is sometimes formed as a result of protein katabolism. Certain cells (in the muscle for instance) can't use Acetyl-CoA to synthesize fatty acid. If there is no immediate need for energy, can the Acetyl-CoA then be exported out of the cell, so that it may be used for fatty acid synthesis in other tissues?

If so, how is this accomplished? I know Acetyl-CoA can be transported out of the mitochondria using the citrate shuttle, but how would it pass the cell membrane and get transported in the blood?